Mac audio software aggregate device issue
I have a 4-input, 4-output hardware device and an 8-input, 8-output virtual device, which I combine into an aggregate device. I am using the SimplyCoreAudio library to get the channel count. The code is as follows:
aggregationDevice!.channels(scope: .input) =>> 12
aggregationDevice!.channels(scope: .output) =>> 12

When the program's MicrophoneMode is set to standard, the channel count is correct. However, when I set the MicrophoneMode to voiceIsolation, the channel count is incorrect:
aggregationDevice!.channels(scope: .input) =>> 4
aggregationDevice!.channels(scope: .output) =>> 12

Below is the code for creating the aggregate device：
func createAggregateDevice(mainDevice: AudioDevice,
                               secondDevice: AudioDevice?,
                               named name: String,
                               uid: String) -> AudioDevice?
    {
        guard let mainDeviceUID = mainDevice.uid else { return nil }

        var deviceList: [[String: Any]] = [
            [
                kAudioSubDeviceUIDKey: mainDeviceUID,
                kAudioSubDeviceDriftCompensationKey:1
            ]
        ]

        // make sure same device isn't added twice
        if let secondDeviceUID = secondDevice?.uid, secondDeviceUID != mainDeviceUID {
            deviceList.append([
                kAudioSubDeviceUIDKey: secondDeviceUID,
                kAudioSubDeviceDriftCompensationKey:1,
                kAudioSubDeviceInputChannelsKey:8
            ])
        }

        let desc: [String: Any] = [
            kAudioAggregateDeviceNameKey: name,
            kAudioAggregateDeviceUIDKey: uid,
            kAudioAggregateDeviceSubDeviceListKey: deviceList,
            kAudioAggregateDeviceMainSubDeviceKey: mainDeviceUID,
            kAudioAggregateDeviceIsPrivateKey:false,
        ]

        var deviceID: AudioDeviceID = 0
        let error = AudioHardwareCreateAggregateDevice(desc as CFDictionary, &deviceID)

        guard error == noErr else {
            return nil
        }

        return AudioDevice.lookup(by: deviceID)
    }


I hope someone can tell me the reason Thank you！

The reason is that voice isolation on macOS has a several year old bug that ruins the input half of aggregate audio devices.
Possible work arounds are:

request that the user not use voice isolation (consult AVCaptureDevice.activeMicrophoneMode)
abandon aggregate audio devices altogether and capture directly from the constituent devices


What are constituent devices? Could you explain in detail, or provide some resources to help learn more about them?

"Constituent devices" are the devices that your aggregate device aggregates. i.e. use the "4-input, 4-output hardware device and an 8-input, 8-output virtual device" separately, without combining them into an aggregate device.

Oh oh aha! Suddenly forgot it
